# How do I publish a react native component to NPM

Tags: react-native, npm

How do I create a React Native component and publish it to NPM? I know I need a GitHub repo but what are the steps? Should there be a specific folder structure? And how do I get it exactly to npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to contribute to the open source community? That’s awesome! Helping to grow React Native’s fairly young ecosystem is great.

When I decided to take on this task not long ago, I noticed there wasn’t much material around publishing React Native components to NPM. So I’m hoping this post will help make the process much easier for others.

**Initial Setup**
First, let’s create a folder where our React Native component will live.

```
mkdir <folder_name> && cd <folder_name>
# For example
mkdir my-component && cd my-component
```

Once inside the folder, we need to initialize a new NPM package by typing npm init. This will create a package.json file that will hold some important metadata about the React Native component.

A series of questions will be displayed such as package name, version, description, keywords, etc.

[Read more](http://on.geeklearn.net/7cd00c9fde)

Answer (score 1):

- Create a local nodejs package directory using npm init ->
  [LINK](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules#how-to-create-nodejs-modules)
- Create a git repo using git init and commit it.
- Add your code and update the git.
- Publish the code to npm. Follow this [LINK](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#how-to-publish--update-a-package)